# how to use a holder class when row views of list view dynamically change

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a list view that changes color when you press it and at the same time a timer starts ticking.

[image]

if you press a row in the list view it changes to:

[image]

I have a onItemClickListener attached to the list view. I recycle my row views with a holder class.

THE PROBLEM is that when I press a row and i scroll somewhere further in the list view, suddenly another row view has also changed color and started counting. I know this is because the views get recycled. But I have no idea how to solve this for the background color and the timer (which is running in separate thread)

this is the getView of my Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder = null;
    TextView txtTitle = null;
    TextView timer = null;
        if(view == null){

            inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            timer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timer);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.textViewTimer = timer;
            viewHolder.textViewOrderNo = txtTitle;
            viewHolder.view = view;
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();
            }

    viewHolder.textViewOrderNo.setText(web[position]);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to Set a `Flag` , `Onclick` change that flag,  so that every time you can check it and change the BackGround in `GetView()` for that particular Position

```
if(checkcondition){
//change color
}else{
//change color
}
```

hope it help you..

Answer (score 0):

Store the state for each row and according make changes it getView()..something similar to this:

> > if(state ==counting) {
> >                      viewHolder.textViewOrderNo.setBackgroundColour(colorCounting);
> >                      viewHolder.textViewOrderNo.setCount(count); }

You will also have to communicate with the counter to get timer status..